# What files should I check in for an SSIS project?

Tags: version-control, ssis

In my SSIS project folder I have extra files in addition to the three package (.dtsx) files that I created. There is a ProjectName.database file, a ProjectName.dtproj file, and a ProjectName.dtproj.user file.

When I build the project, the dtsx files are copied to a folder called "bin" inside the project folder.

When I create a deployment manifest, the three package files are copied to a folder called "bin/Deployment" along with a new ProjectName.SSISDeploymentManifest file.

Which of these files should I check in to source control?

I think only the three package files and the deployment manifest are useful to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will want to keep:

- *.dtsx - your packages
- *.dtproj file - project files
- .sln file - solution file - if You have only one project you might not have this one
- *.database - take a look at quotation below
- deployment manifest file - allows you to deploy your packages to a target location using a wizard

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138028.aspx) states following:

> The *.database file contains information that Business Intelligence Development Studio requires to open the Integration Services project.

*.dtproj.user and .sln.suo files are not needed because they (from the same link): contain information about your preferences for working with the project.