# Which reporting services file types are safe to ignore on git?

Tags: git, github, reporting-services, gitignore, ignore

I looked this up and almost every answer linked to a [gitignore repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore) or a [website](https://www.gitignore.io). However, upon inspection I've found that it doesn't ignore files that I'm  having problems with.

The files in question are:

- PROJECTNAME **.rds**
- Reports **.rptproj.user**
- Reports **.rptproj.rsuser**
- **.smss_suo**

Which of these files are safe to ignore? Which are not? And for what reasons?

Thanks!

Comment: An incomplete answer hence a comment only. rsuser is good to ignore (and I found problems if I didn't) as it is user specific. An .rds file is a report data source and an essential part of the project, so don't ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on what you want to track in source control. I'd say *typically* files prefixed with a "dot" are safe to ignore/exclude from source control.

Some of your files contain the word "user" which would imply they're user-specific files and shouldn't be committed; otherwise, each user would likely have diff changes for these files each time they worked on the project, which probably isn't what you want. I see one file has "suo" which is a Visual Studio convention for "solution user options", and the same logic applies there too.

I'd assume you want to track `PROJECTNAME.rds` in source control, and you wouldn't want to track the others.

Comment: Wondering the same thing. What about .rds? I've read this file is important somehow, but I'm sorta newish when it comes to Reporting Services and I'm working on another side of the project while getting this ready so that it can be checked out as clean as possible by new collaborators.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's in the file so I can't say whether you'd want to track it in source control. Is the entire file name ".rds" or does it just have an ".rds" extension e.g. "my-file.rds"?

Comment: All of them are extensions, meaning something like `title.rds`, `title.rptproj.user`, and `title.rptproj.rsuser`. The only exception is the `.smss_suo` which has no file name.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess its the bit about 'files prefixed by a dot'. the files mentioned by the questioner don't start with a dot, they're just files containing a dot to indicate the file extension type.

Comment: @Nimchip RDS is a report data source, which is normally a database or cube that your reports will point to. it is as essential a part of your project as a RDL (report file) or RSD (shared dataset) so you need to keep all those.

Comment: @Rich do you know if `Filename.dtproj` is safe to ignore?

Comment: Nevermind, I read an article saying it might be important. What a mess reporting services has for version control tracking. Yeez!

Comment: @Nimchip Can you link to the article? What is the file used for?

Comment: @styfle unfortunately i lost the link to it, but have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756620/what-files-should-i-check-in-for-an-ssis-project

Comment: @Nimchip a bit late but this forum gives more information about the files: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64f81201-4cec-47e8-a905-c8c792452d32/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-rptprojuser-file In short: the `.rsuser` file stores your connection strings and passwords (encrypted). I don't really have a conclusion though...